# InDesign - Automatically add break frame after a paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, paragraph-styles

Is there a possibility to force a frame break after a paragraph style?

I have a "Chapter" paragraph style on odd pages and I want to force automatically the next paragraph (which can be headings, text or anything else) to start on the next even page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Keep Options` under your paragraph style definition and experiment a little. You'll probably need to adjust more that one style for this to work, I can't get very specific because we have not seen your specific setup and all these options can affect your text flow in different ways.

Here's a guide on how to use these: https://www.creativepro.com/keep-options-interact

[image]